# How to Handle MessageBox Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern(MVVM Light ToolKit)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am making a windows phone 7 and trying to do it using MVVM. I would like to keep my view model as clean as possible but I am unsure on how to make a dialog box. I am using MVVM light and I know they have Messaging system or something but not really sure how to use it.

I would like to use  `Guide.BeginShowMessageBox` as this seems to give more features than the standard dialog box.

How can I do this without breaking the MVVM pattern. AS when I load up the view I want to have a loaded trigger to be triggered and then check some conditions. If conditions are met show the Dialog.

// Vm

```
public RelayCommand MainPageLoaded
    {
        get
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                // breaks MVVM now as have view code in viewmodel. Need to take out somehow
                Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Test", "Test network", new List<string>() { "Yes", "No" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, asyncResult =>
                    {
                        int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
                        // if yes then work offline mode? Maybe another property in ViewModel will get set to say offline mode?
                    }, null);
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            // Not sure what to put here.
        }
    }
```

// View

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger>
        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MainPageLoaded}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Edit**
Another problem I am having is. I have a list that is bound to some data that is stored in this property

```
   public ObservableCollection<ContactGroup> ContactGroups { get; set; }
```

then on tap I have a relaycommand that should be triggered

```
 public ICommand GroupContactTapped
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<GestureEventArgs>(e =>
                {
                    var selectedTextBlock = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;

                    MessageBox.Show(selectedTextBlock.Tag.ToString());
                });
            }
        }
```

Yet I don't know how to find which object was "tapped" without casting the source to a textblock.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Updated my question to make it clear. Also added some code I been trying with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it truly means to follow "the MVVM pattern" is a very subjective thing.
For instance, some people will say you shouldn't show/launch a messagebox (of any type) from the VM, while others will say this is fine.

As with any ambiguity, you'll need to balance adherence to a pattern, with what's most appropriate for a specific project, with what's appropriate for the people developing and maintaining the code base.

In terms of MvvmLight, the messaging system it uses is for communicating from a viewmodel to either another viewmodel or a view, not for displaying messages to the user.

If you are going to use `Guide.BeginShowMessageBox`, particularly from a viewmodel, beware that it is non-blocking. If you want it to behave like a "regular" `MessageBox` you'll need to use it with a `ManualResetEvent` so that it's not possible to continue to interact with the app while the messagebox is displayed.

Comment: Ya that's what I am thinking with MVVM pattern what effort to reward. I mean sometimes it is just easier and cleaner to do it one way and might not be 100% proper then writing tons of code and making it harder to read. If I where to do the MVVM way how do you do it then?

Comment: @chobo2 there is no "one MVVM way" to show a messagebox. If you want to be as "pure" as possible: inject a service into the viewmodel that can show the messagebox, and then call into that service to show the messagebox when required.

Comment: Hmm kinda of weird to me as when I think of services I think about service layers what should be as clean as possible and not have that kind of code in it as well but that is for web apps. So everytime I need to do something in the VM like that I need to use a service? How about in this case? I have a gesture(RelayCommand) and I want to find its source var selectedTextBlock = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock; Would I have to move that line to a service and Pass in e?

Comment: @chobo2 in that instance you probably wouldn't need a service and you shouldn't be referring to the TextBlock. Services are typically used to interact with items outside of the ViewModel, like the file system or UI (e.g. to show a messagebox). Don't refer to the TextBlock directly, add a command parameter which is the [sub]viewModel or viewmodel property you're actually interested in.

Comment: I don't get it I already have a RelayCommand setup with the event I want to capture but I don't get what you mean by [sub]viewModel. You saying I need to pass the Source to another Vm?

Comment: @chobo2 assuming that your button is on an item in a list which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<SomeObject>` it'll be the instance of the `SomeObject` that you'll want. This is what I meant by sub-viewmodel - an object that is a (probably) viewmodel in it's own tight but not the one providing the DataContext of the page.

Comment: I will post what I have. I am still not following. Like I do bind a list with an OvservableCollection but I don't see how I get the right object out of that collection without casting it to a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have one mainpage/view that hosts all the other views, like a mainwindow:
I send a message event from the viewmodels, and the dialog box is handled in the code behind of the main window.  This is the only codebehind I have in my project so I find it acceptable that the rest of the project can be strictly MVVM, with this one exception.

I send the message with the following (converted from VB so it might need work):

```
object message = new DialogMessage("YourMessage", YourFunctionThatHandlesCallback) {
    Button = MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
    Caption = "Caption Goes Here"
};
Messenger.Default.Send(message);
```

I register for the dialog box with the following in the main page code behind:

```
Partial Public Class MainWindow
  Inherits Window

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    ''single initialization of messanger for catching message box
    Messenger.[Default].Register(Of DialogMessage)(Me, Sub(msg)
                                                           Dim result = MessageBox.Show(msg.Content, msg.Caption, msg.Button, MessageBoxImage.Warning)
                                                           ''Send callback
                                                           msg.ProcessCallback(result)
                                                       End Sub)
  End Sub
End Class
```

I could not succesfully convert the C# lambda so I had to leave it in VB.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a [MessageBoxService](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit%20%28WP71%29/Services/MessageBoxService.cs) in the [Cimbalino Phone Windows Toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit)!
You can use that in a MVVM architecture.